# N para N Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Caros,  Estou tentando realizar um relacionamento N para N no Entity Framework para as tabelas descritas abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento o que tá acontecendo, é uma redundância cíclica, onde cada vez que eu abro um Group[x].GroupUser[x] nesse ponto eu consigo tanto voltar para Group como seguir para User, e de User voltar para GroupUser e assim para Group, isso é normal? Não seria uma redundância cíclica? Estou fazendo errado? Olha a imagem abaixo. Agradeço a ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é um comportamento normal, dado que está acontecendo nas propriedades de navegação (que são referencias para objetos). O EF entende que a navegação é bidirecional (user -> group / group -> user), e ele apenas coloca os elementos apontando para a mesma referencia. Pode averiguar que a referencia de cada objeto é a mesma.

Se você for usar bibliotecas como Automapper para copiar dinamicamente os elementos, você terá problemas com overflow. Mas isso pode ser resolvido de algumas maneiras: se você não precisa carregar os objetos relacionados pode optar por desativar o LazyLoading. Se você precisa dos objetos relacionados, você pode usar as configurações do automapper para não se aprofundar mais do que alguns níveis nas referencias de objetos.